# socketio and zend integration (routing)

Tags: php, node.js, zend-framework, socket.io

Im currently trying to to a real time dashboard, showing online user on a based url.

Using a nodejs/socketIO and a zend platform(1).
When my page try socket.emit();

```
Request URL:http://mysite.local/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LlEm2ig
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

But getting this error:

Fatal error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (socket.io)
```

I think I'm supposed to do somethings in my bootstrap (routing or somethings) but can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
Request URL:http://mysite.local/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LlEm2ig
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

mysite.local was calling 127.0.0.1, but not the NodeJs server On 127.0.0.1:5000

Hope this can help someone :D